# Vertical align a shape line near the right border

Tags: android, android-drawable

I've troubles aligning a line shape near the right border of the drawable.
I use this code.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:right="-120dp">
    <rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:fromDegrees="90" android:toDegrees="90">
        <shape android:shape="line">
            <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#000000"/>
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
```

The line actually goes outside the drawable because the right border is not at a fixed position of 120dp. How can I put it at the right border independently from the container width.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:top="-1dp" android:bottom="-1dp" android:left="-1dp">
    <shape >
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#FFFF" />
    </shape>
  </item>
</layer-list>
```